# Net::ReadTimeout when connecting remotely using selenium in Ruby

Tags: ruby, docker, selenium, selenium-webdriver, docker-compose

I want to use selenium with Ruby on DockerCompose and chrome on another server, but I get an error.
The following are the various codes and errors.

- DockerCompose.yml

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  ruby:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: RubyDockerFile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    tty: true
  chrome:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome:4.0.0-beta-3-20210426
    container_name: chrome
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    ports:
      - 4444:4444
      - 5900:5900
      - 7900:7900
```

- Ruby Code in RubyDocker

```rb
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :remote, url: 'http://chrome:4444', desired_capabilities: :chrome
```

- Error

```sh
Net::ReadTimeout: Net::ReadTimeout with #<TCPSocket:(closed)>
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-mini-profiler-2.3.1/lib/patches/net_patches.rb:19:in `block in request_with_mini_profiler'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-mini-profiler-2.3.1/lib/mini_profiler/profiling_methods.rb:46:in `step'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-mini-profiler-2.3.1/lib/patches/net_patches.rb:18:in `request_with_mini_profiler'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.7/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:129:in `response_for'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.7/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:82:in `request'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.7/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:64:in `call'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.7/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:167:in `execute'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.7/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:102:in `create_session'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.7/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:56:in `handshake'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.7/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/driver.rb:39:in `initialize'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.7/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:58:in `new'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.7/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:58:in `for'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.7/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:88:in `for'
/hoge.rake:9:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
```

Comment: This error happens when page load exceeds 60 seconds. Is your page load takes more than 60 seconds?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I was able to connect by setting the timeout to 180 seconds, but not 120 seconds. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Yes, that's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I extend the timeout, I can now connect.

```rb
    client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
    client.read_timeout = 180 # seconds
    driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :remote, url: 'http://chrome:4444', desired_capabilities: :chrome, :http_client => client
```

Answer (score 0):

In our case, it turned out to be an issue with MTU under Docker-in-Docker (how our CI platform works).

The fix was to lower the MTU by adding the following to our `docker-compose.yml` used in CI:

```
networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge
    driver_opts:
      com.docker.network.driver.mtu: 1450
```

My coworker wrote this up here: https://chen.do/docker-in-docker-dind-mtu-fix-for-docker-compose/

The actual symptoms can be varied and surprising, but it was confirmed when we opened a shell in one of the inner Docker containers and were able to ping and `curl https://example.com` fine but certain requests would just hang (often at TLS negotiation) indefinitely.

There